# Read a cell based of numerical input for IF command

Tags: excel, excel-formula, autocomplete

I am designing a Material Resource Plan using Excel. I have a two week lead on parts with lot sizes of 90. To auto fill the fields, I would like to be able to input '2' and have Excel recognize that if cell E30 (Planned Order Receipt) has a value, that C31 (Planned Order Release) should display the lot size (as in two weeks prior an order should be placed). Is this type of function possible?

[image]

Comment: `IF(E30<>"",B24,"")` - assuming B24 is the Lot cell.

Comment: It is! Thank you! This worked just fine!

Comment: However, you still need to define the cell within the Release cell and not by selecting Lead = '2' cell. That is, by changing 2 to 3, then the cell read would be F30 (week 4 Receipt) and input 90 into C31 (week 1 release).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=IF(NOT(INDEX(ISBLANK($D$30:F30),B23)),B24,"")
```

where `$D$30:F30` represents the value of **Planned Order Receipt** from Week 2 to Week 4. If you have more than 4 weeks, replace `F30` with the actual ending cell of this range (and suggest to use absolute cell reference i.e. putting a dollar sign `$` in front both column and row ID).

> **ISBLANK** function will check each cell in the range `$D$30:F30` is blank (not returned by a formula but a real blank cell), and return a range of `TRUE` or `FALSE`.
>
> **INDEX** function will return the corresponding `TRUE` or `FALSE` based on the lead number you entered. If you enter `2`, INDEX will return the second value from the range, so on so forth.
>
> **NOT** function will reverse `FALSE` to `TRUE` i.e. `TRUE` for a non-blank cell. Then **IF** function will return the lot number as desired, but return a blank `""` if that's not the case. You did not specify what you would like to return if the **Planned Order Receipt** is blank so I just used blank `""`.

Comment: Hello. Thank you but unfortunately this did not work correctly. I think it was because it read all the cells all the time and when I copied and pasted it over to other cells in the row, the 90 appeared in all of them.

Comment: @MatthewOlson firstly, did you enter the formula in Cell `C31`? secondly, are the blank cells in Row 30 returned by a formula or simply blank without any formulas in them? lastly, is your actual data range the same as in your screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

I did some searching today and ask Dr. Google a little differently. I was able to locate this solution using the Offset function: 
=OFFSET(C26,4,$B$23,1,1)